# Call vector destructor or clear in a different thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stdvector

I have huge vector of unique_ptr .

When I need to do clear() or call destructor it took 4-5 seconds.

One theoretical way to speed it up is to create temp vector, swap it with the huge vector I work, then start a thread and call clear on temp vector.

When looking over internet i do not see anyone speaking for optimization like this.

Is there a flaw In my optimization?

Comment: Sounds feasible ... maybe you could come up with a different allocation scheme so you have a lesser number of larger allocations

Comment: The reason no one is talking about it is a mixture of: You have a very specialized request + it's kinda intuitive and trivial (sorry for being blunt).

Comment: fyi: You might not see all the benefits you expect from this technique - the heap is a shared resource and needs to be locked when allocating/deleting.  So your background thread is going to "own" the heap until it has finished deleting the vector.  Allocations in your main thread (eg std::string, std::vector etc) will have to contend for the heap lock.

Comment: Can you figure out why it is taking so long?

Comment: couple of million elements, each with different size - strings are good approximations. also custom new and delete operators. https://github.com/nmmmnu/HM4/blob/master/hm4/pairblob.h

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your idea should work. For example, if you have a `std::vector` of some data called `X`:

```
struct X
{
    // some data here
};

using DataStorage = std::vector<std::unique_ptr<X>>;
```

you might use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) to move `DataStorage` object and call `clear()` on this object asynchronously:

```
DataStorage data;

// data usage

auto clear_task = std::async(std::launch::async,
    &DataStorage::clear, std::move(data));

// do some stuff here; data object is not used anymore

clear_task.wait();
```

There are no unnecessary copying here: you just move `data` and specify that you want to call `clear()` in a separate thread so that the main thread does not hang while clear operation is performed.

Comment: yes, the point of swap / move is you can use empty vector immediately.

Comment: @Nick I suppose that you cannot use `std::vector` after move. But you might do the swap as you've mentioned and deal with empty vector.